# How to deal with tax in quotation with multi company option?

Tags: odoo, quotations, tax

This question is about how to deal with tax in quotation with multi company option. Please take below scenario:

1) I have enabled multi companies feature and lets say I have 2 comapnies C1, C2.

2) I have two taxes T1(with company C1) and T2(with company C2).

3) I made products P1 with tax T1 and P2 with tax T2.

4) Consider I have set C1 as current company in the user settings.

5) Now, whenever I make Quotation and select both these products then, for P1 it shows tax in order line and for P2 it does not show taxes. It is so because I have set C1 as current company.

6) If i change current company in user settings from C1 to C2 then in the new quotation, now it will show tax for product P2 not for P1. It is so because I have set C2 as current company!!! i have to set the taxes manually for product P1.

How to get rid of this? I want to apply tax on the order line irrespective of the current company.

Answer (score 0):

In **Account Tax** company field is **available and required**, when you create **sale order line** then system will **set tax based on login user company**.now let say **if you select product P2** but if there is not **any login user company tax available in product P2** then **system will not set any tax in P2 product line**.

You need to create **two taxes** for both company.

Ex : You should create tax **T1/T2** for **both company**, so total there are **four taxes** in your system.**two taxes** per company.

In Product you can set **multiple taxes**.In product **P1 you can set tax T1/T2** same in **product P2 you can set tax T1/T2**.

After that When you **login with company C1** and **add two products** then system will set **C1 company tax in both product lines**. It will work for another company as well.

This may help you.

Comment: Hi Emipro technologies. Thanks for your response.

Suppose, I have around 10 taxes per company and I have 6 companies then in my system there will be 360 taxes!!! Do you think this solution is feasible? Isn't there any configuration from Odoo regarding this or will it be customization?

Comment: Odoo provide fiscal position,based on customer country system will set tax in sale order line, you can check fiscal position in detail.it may help you.